# Confusion with denotations and potentially other things as well

Tags: shors-algorithm

In the article [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719) there is an optimized circuit for Shor's algorithm:

[image]

and I'm not sure if $x=11$ is the random number $1<x<N$ I can choose to calculate $f(r)= x^r\bmod N$ for $r=1,2,3,4\ldots$ which will lead to the period $r$.

Namely, as far as I understand this circuit and the further description which can be found on page 31, $x$ is the random number that I can choose.
The resulting outcome of the given circuit after running it on the IBM Quantum Composer is $00100$ or $4$ denoted with $p$. Further, in the article, it is said that $M/p= 8/4 =2$ where $M$ is $2^n$, $n$ being the number of qubits in the control register giving $r=2$.

Inserting $r=0,1,2,3,4,...$ in $x^{r} \bmod 15$ I obtain $1,11,1,11,1,\ldots$ resulting in a period of $2$.

Now, what confuses me is that I'm not sure if the result of the given circuit is the period (4) and I got the meaning of $x$ wrong, if $r=2$ is the period and the result obtained $(4)$ isn't, or if both $p=4$ and $r=2$ are periods of the function, but we have to make sure if there is a smaller one than the obtained one and that's the reason why we divide by $2$.

The last paragraph can be summarized as the question:
What is the meaning of the obtained result of the given circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit does not return the period itself but a value $y = M/r$. It holds that $M=2^n$, where $n$ is number of qubits used for representation of $y$. In your particular case $n=3$, hence $M=8$. The returned value of $y$ is 4 (note that also 0 has high probability but this results is deemed "trivial" and it is neglected). Easily $r = M/y = 8/4 = 2$ which is the period.

After that you can calculate factors $p,q = \gcd\{a^{r/2}\pm1;N\} = \gcd\{11\pm1;15\}$, i.e. $p =\gcd\{12;15\}=3$ and $q =\gcd\{10;15\}=5$.

Comment: Thank you very much.